# Split List into sublists based on border values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I would like to split up an existing sorted list into multiple sublists, based on the entries of another list.

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
List<int> myList = [1,3,7,23,56,58,164,185];
```

and another list, which defines at which places `myList` should be split:

```
List<int> borders = [4,59,170];
```

What's the shortest way to get a nested list where `myList` is split at the values defined in `borders`, i.e. like this:

```
[[1,3],[7,23,56,58],[164],[185]]
```

I have already solved it by manually looping through the lists, but I can imagine it's easier and shorter using Linq.

EDIT: There is one simplification: numbers can't be the same as the borders, so it's impossible that a number is contained in `myList` and `borders` at the same time.

Comment: Can you post your already code?

Comment: Look into Linq's `.TakeWhile`

Comment: You should describe how your system should handle numbers that fall exactly on a border (if possible).

Comment: @user2946329 i will when I get back to my other machine

Comment: @JonSenchyna sorry, I totally forgot that. Borders can't be the same as the numbers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you want to group the numbers into different groups, you will want to use `GroupBy`. The difficulty is only what you use as the key. For this, you can use the largest border value that is smaller than the number. This assumes that `borders` is sorted though:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int> { 1, 3, 7, 23, 56, 58, 164, 185 };
List<int> borders = new List<int> { 4, 59, 170 };

var groups = myList.GroupBy(i => borders.LastOrDefault(x => x < i));

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", group.Key, string.Join(", ", group));
}
```

This yields the following output:

```
0: 1, 3
4: 7, 23, 56, 58
59: 164
170: 185
```

Note that this is not exactly the most efficient solution as it will search for an appropriate border key for every element in `myList`. If your list is sorted like your example, then it’s more efficient to loop through both at the same time and just match the numbers of `myList` to the current or next border element. So this solution is `O(n * m)` while a solution `O(n)` is possible. On the plus side, this allows `myList` to be completely unsorted.

---

For those interested in a O(n) solution, here’s one possible take on it which is just a very general way on grouping sequences:

```
List<List<int>> groups = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> group = null;
int k = -1;
foreach (int num in myList)
{
    if (k < 0 || num > borders[k])
    {
        group = new List<int>();
        groups.Add(group);
        k++;
    }
    group.Add(num);
}
```

Comment: dont want to put it as answer. because yours better. but i did this  `var newList = borders.Select(x => myList.TakeWhile(y => y < x).ToList()).ToList();`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary That’s a good idea, but it will repeatedly take the smaller numbers. So 1 and 3 for example are in all groups. Also, your solution will only give you `borders.Count` many sections, so `185` in this case is missing completely.

Comment: oh. yeah i really missed it. awesome!